# Debian rules files determine init

Tags: packaging, debian, init

I want to modify the gdm3 package. I need a `ifeq` condition in the rules file, which should check whether systemd is installed. If systemd is the init system, then different build options are used. I thought about using the SYSTEMD_EXEC_PID environment variable, how can I do this?